# C error free(): double free detected in tcache 2 in an array manipulation

Tags: arrays, c, parameter-passing

**What have to do**

My function is given an array of n numbers and should create and return a new array whose content depends on the parameter k:

if k>0 the new array must contain every number of a repeated k times consecutively; for example if a=[1 0 8 2] and k=3 the new array must be [1 1 1 0 0 0 8 8 8 2 2 2]

if k=0 the new array must have the same length as a but contain only zeros; for example if a=[1 0 8 2] and k=0 the new array must be [0 0 0 0]

if k<0 the new array must contain each element of a repeated k times but in reverse order; for example if a=[1 0 8 2] and k=-2 the new array must be [2 2 8 8 0 0 1 1]

The function must return the pointer to the first element of the result array and store its length in *newn.

The main function has to read from the command line the name of an input file and a series of integers integer1, integer2, ... integerK, then reads the integers stored in the input file into an array (terminates if there are none)
For each integer on the command line it calls the `elabora` function passing it the array and integers and writes the elements of the array returned by elaborate to stdout. The program should not print anything else to stdout, debug messages in stderr
For example, if the program is invoked by writing

`main test1 2 0 -1`
and the infile contains the integers
2
0
5
1
the program must print the 3 lines
2 2 0 0 5 5 1 1
0 0 0 0
1 5 0 2

The program must close all files and deallocate all used memory.

**This is my code**

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE 
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <stdbool.h> 
#include <assert.h>   
#include <string.h>   
#include <errno.h>


void termina(const char *messaggio);

int *elabora(int a[], int n, int k, int *nuovon) {
  int c = 0;
  
  nuovon = malloc(n*sizeof(int));
  if(nuovon==NULL) termina("Memoria insufficiente");
  
  for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
    if(k>0) {
      for(int j=0; j<k; j++) {
          nuovon[c]=a[j];
          c++;
      }
    } else if(k==0) {
      nuovon[c] = 0;
      c++;
    } else {
      for(int j=k-1; j>=0; j--) {
        nuovon[c]=a[j];
        c++;
      }
    }
  }
  *nuovon = n*k;
  return nuovon;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

  if(argc<2) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Uso: %s i1 [i2 i3 ...]\n", argv[0]);
      exit(1);
  }
  
  int n = 10;
  int *nuovon = NULL;
  int k = atoi(argv[2]);
  int i;
  int *a = malloc(n*sizeof(int));
  if(a==NULL) termina("Memoria insufficiente");
  
  // lettura file
  FILE *f = fopen(argv[1], "r");
  if(f==NULL) termina("Impossibile aprire il file di inpt");
  // lettura interi
  int e = fscanf(f, "%d", &n);
  if(e!=1) {
    termina("Non ci sono interi nel file");
    fprintf(stderr, "Errore di lettura nella riga %d\n", i);
  }
  //chiusura file
  fclose(f);

  for(int i=2; i<argc; i++) {
    nuovon = elabora(a, n, k, nuovon);
    for(int j=0; j<n*k; j++) {
        fprintf(stdout, "%d", nuovon[j]);
    }
  }
  free(nuovon);
  free(a);
  return 0;
}

void termina(const char *messaggio){
  if(errno!=0) perror(messaggio);
    else fprintf(stderr,"%s\n", messaggio);
  exit(1);
}
```

**Error**

when I run it with
`main test1 2 0 5 1`
It was given me no warning cause I fixed them, but now it shows just some random 0s as output.

Comment: You have the three statements `free(nuovon); return nuovon; *nuovon = n*k;`. Please take some time to think about them, and what they do. And how often `free(nuovon)` will be called in your program.

Comment: What do you think this sequence does? `free(nuovon); return nuovon; *nuovon = n*k;`

Comment: Your code also calls `fclose()` twice on a file. `fclose(f);
  if(fclose(f)!=0) ` You're not supposed to do that.

Comment: I removed the first `free(nuovon)` cause I didnt noticed that I called it twice, I adjust the fclose, I'm a beginner in C so thank you all, but now instead of the numbers it's show just some random 0 as output, I'm trying to fix that now

Comment: One thing to remember is that `return` exits the function. No code after that is executed.